# Process files in numerical order

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Where this script is located, I have multiple sub-directories in which I would like to run a single command on all of the contents. The contents are also numbered in ascending order. Using `for f in *` in folders with 10+ items results in files named `10` or `11` coming sequentially before `1..9`.

Additionally, The number of files in each sub-directory varies between 6 and 12 items so I don't think I can simply do a range operation like `{1..12}` because I would like to avoid warnings/errors about nonexistent files.

**Question**: Is there a way to force or modify the for loop to maintain ascending numerical order when iterating over the entire contents of a folder without knowing the quantity of the folders contents?

```
term=""                  # hold accumulated filenames

for d in */ ; do         # iterate over sub-directories
    cd $d
    for f in * ; do      # iterate over files in sub-directory
        term="$term $f"
    done
    # run a command using the string $term
    term=""
    cd ..
done
```

Side note: I tagged `sh`, `shell` and `bash` since they are all applicable to this problem. I read [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash) before adding both tags to ensure it would be a valid choice even though there are some syntax/portability variations and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ls` option `-v` for this. From `man ls`:

> `-v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text`

If you change your inner loop to

```
for f in `ls -v` ; do      # iterate over files in sub-directory
    term="$term $f"
done
```

The results from `ls` will be sorted ascending numerical order.

Another option is `sort`, from `man sort`:

> `-g, --general-numeric-sort
>                 compare according to general numerical value`

Piping the results from `ls` through `sort -g` gives the same result.

**Edit**

Since using the output of `ls` to get filenames [is a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), consider also using `find` instead, e.g.

```
for f in `find * -type f | sort -g`; do
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the example @resc, it helps.